# Loading a class from single jar among several jars

Tags: java, maven, classloader

I want to you use a class  'javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory' in code.
The class (XMLOutputFactory) is available in more than one jars of library which got included as maven dependencies.
Problem : The class(XMLOutputFactory) is loading from the jar file while i am expecting to load from other jar.
Is there any solution to customize the loading of a class from the specific jar file.

Comment: `javax.xml.stream.XMLOutputFactory` is in the core JRE class library by default as of Java 6, so you don't need any third-party JAR to have access to it.  It should just be a case of going through the dependency-report and excluding any `xml-apis` and `stax-api` transitive dependencies you find.

Answer (score 2):

Not on the java side (or maybe by implementing a new classloader but that is not a reasonable solution to your problem).

You should probably just exclude the dependencies (versions) you don't want in your pom file.

Answer (score 1):

Since maven 2.0.9 the classpath is generated according dependencies declaration in pom.xml.

From [maven site](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html):

> Note that if two dependency versions are at the same depth in the dependency tree, until Maven 2.0.8 it was not defined which one would win, but since Maven 2.0.9 it's the order in the declaration that counts: the first declaration wins.

So you can solve your problem if you take care of dependencies ordering in your pom.xml